# dotNetRDF not parsing LinkedMovie.nt (VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfParseException)

Tags: dotnetrdf

I have tested linkedmdb-18-05-2009-dump.nt on Java Apache Jena, but on dotNetRDF throwing an exception as

```
VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfParseException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=Invalid URI encountered, see inner exception for details
Source=dotNetRDF
StackTrace:
  at VDS.RDF.Parsing.NTriplesParser.TryParseUri(TokenisingParserContext context, String uri)
  at VDS.RDF.Parsing.NTriplesParser.TryParseTriple(TokenisingParserContext context)
  at VDS.RDF.Parsing.NTriplesParser.Parse(TokenisingParserContext context)
  at VDS.RDF.Parsing.NTriplesParser.Load(IRdfHandler handler, TextReader input)
  at ConsoleApp2_RDFWALKTHROUGH.Program.Main(String[] args) in 

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
```

my c# code is as follow:

```
String inputFile = "D:/linkedmdb-18-05-2009-dump.nt";

IGraph g = new Graph();
NTriplesParser parser = new NTriplesParser(NTriplesSyntax.Original);

Console.WriteLine("RDF DS-1 Loading Started:");

parser.Load(g, new StreamReader(inputFile));

Console.WriteLine("RDF DS-1 Loading Finished:");

Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(loadingTime).ToShortTimeString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Please guide me where I am wrong because it's very confusing that the same file is ok on Java but not parsing on dotNetRDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the dump contains an invalid IRI. At line 3104575 in the dump I downloaded from [https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~oktie/linkedmdb/](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Eoktie/linkedmdb/) there is the following:

```
<http://data.linkedmdb.org/film/9995> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/page> <http://?> .
```

The last IRI on that line is the one that is causing the parser to choke as `?` is not a valid character at that position in an IRI.

Comment: Thanks, but how could I remove it or prevent dotnetRDF to read it, I am totally new in it

Comment: Sadly there isn't a way to get dotNetRDF to skip lines that don't parse correctly - so every line in the file has to be correct. I think the quickest way to fix this would be to just go into the dump file and remove the error. As the format used (n-triples) is a line-oriented format, it is safe just to delete the entire line.

Comment: Thanks, Kal; program run successfully after removing the invalid IRI line from the dump.